# correct way to use specific jvm to run java code on machine that has multiple jvms

Tags: java, environment-variables

I have a situation where I have multiple jvms on a pc. Now I want to run java code using a specific jvm, how do I do that?
I did do

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\special\jre\bin\jvm.dll
```

but it doesn't seem to work as before or after when I do java -version, I always get the same, currently installed java e.g

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1098]
    (c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    C:\Windows\System32>java -version
    java version "1.8.0_241"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
    Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode, sharing)

    C:\Windows\System32>
```

where as I am hoping that once I do the set java_home, it should work with that specific jvm?
I know I am making some trivial mistake here, can some one please guide?
Thanks in advance

Comment: When you type just "java" on the command line, that's located using the PATH variable, not JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Thanks, how do I point to specific JVm to run my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you run as,

```
C:\special\jre\bin java -version //desired vesrion
```

You need to set a PATH variable,

```
JAVA_SPECIAL_HOME = C:\special\jre\
```

And run as,

```
%JAVA_SPECIAL_HOME%\bin\java
```

Answer (score 0):

**PATH** is a special variable that points on a folder where windows can find the executable file (not necessarily java, but java in this case). So if you have, say, java 10 in the path, open up `cmd` and type `java -version` - you'll see java 10. 
If you have many folders with "java.exe" - the one that appears first will be launched.

**JAVA_HOME**, on the contrary, has nothing to do with Windows - its a "convention" - many other programs (like IDEs) can assume that if you have an environment variable called `JAVA_HOME`- it should point on JDK installation, that's it.

So if you have multiple JVMs installed on the same computer - you'll have to point explicitly on bin/java.exe of `jdk/jre` of your choice. This can be done by using JAVA_HOME or without.

On my personal windows system (and I use many Java installation) I usually define the following (I assume all jdk-s are installed in folder "Java", it can be Program Files or whatever):

---

JAVA_8_HOME=C:\Java\jdk8

JAVA_9_HOME=C:\Java\jdk9

...

JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_14_HOME%

PATH=... %JAVA_HOME%\bin

By default I would like to use java 14 for example, but I will be able to switch the default in future. For this, I'll edit the JAVA_HOME definition and point it to another JAVA

---

Now I want to run something with a default java (which should be ok in the most cases) - I don't think about this at all - just run `java -jar Myjar.jar`

If I want some specific java (for example java 8) - I can do `%JAVA_8_HOME%\bin\java -jar Myjar.jar`